# What is the adjoint of the linear operator $T(\alpha)=(\alpha|\beta)(\gamma)$ where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are fixed vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $V$ be an inner product (not necessarily finite dimensional). Let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be fixed vectors.Then does there exist an adjoint of the linear operator of $T$ defined as  $T(\alpha)=(\alpha|\beta)(\gamma)$ and if so then what will be the adjoint of $T$.

I am stuck in this question for a very long time. If $V$ is finite dimensional then adjoint of $T$ exists. If $V$ is not finite dimensional then how do I show that adjoint exists? I think if it exists then I will be able to show what it is.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about whether $V$ is finite-dimensional. Try assuming the adjoint eixsts, and try figuring out what it must be. Then, you can verify your proposed solution works for general $V$ by substituting it into the equation $(Tv \mid w) = (v \mid T^* w)$.

Comment: Did you get any further with it? Try playing with the expression $(Tv \mid w)$, which equals $((v \mid \beta)\gamma \mid w)$, until you get something of the form $(v \mid \underline{\quad})$. It shouldn't take more than a few steps.

Comment: yes  I got $T^*(y)=(y|\gamma)\beta$

Comment: Excellent! That's correct.